# Forwarding Udp Traffic With Proxy Tools

Tags: proxy, udp, haproxy, portforwarding, envoyproxy

We want to forward the logs coming to the central log server to various clusters by using proxy tools (envoy, Haproxy etc.). But while doing this, some proxies cannot do the UDP forwarding process. (For example, Haproxy). If we think that the traffic routing process is solved, this time, the sending IP address appears as the proxy IP address that we use in the meantime, as a result of the traffic from the senders to the target servers. Is there a different proxy where we can forward the traffic so that we can see which sender IP address it is coming from without appearing like this? (For UDP). I am waiting for your suggestions to provide a solution with the highest performance tools.

[I want to make an orientation like in the image in the example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ2OY.png)

I couldn't forward UDP traffic. Even if I forward the traffic, the proxy IP in the central log server appears as the sending IP instead of the sending IP address. What I want is to see the sending IP in traffic, not the Proxy IP.

Answer (score 0):

Proxies relies on TCP to function, you are looking at doing network address translation instead of proxy functionality.

Comment: I think you didn't understand this problem sry.

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy should be able to do this. It‘s also possible to load balance.

https://www.haproxy.com/blog/log-forwarding-with-haproxy-and-syslog

https://jmagnin.github.io/2020/10/10/syslog-load-balancing-with-haproxy.html